# Concat rows based on id and move them to different csv python

Tags: python

I have two csv files that look like this:
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

I want to concat those based on id and move them to a different csv (to something that looks like this):
[image]

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import difflib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


movies_data = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
tags_data=pd.read_csv('tags.csv')
df=pd.merge(movies_data,tags_data, on="movieId", how='outer')
print(df.head())
```

But I get this and that's not what I want:
[image]

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Achieve what? You mention "that's not what I want" but we don't know what you DO want. Please replace all pictures with text/code and provide your expected output.

Comment: sorry, but please read as I said: I want to concat those based on id and move them to a different csv (to something that looks like this):

Answer (score 0):

the way I understood the problem:
given the dataframe of movies and the dataframe of user-feedback, make a dataframe, which has a row for each movie, containing a large string with all user-feedback for that movie (seperated by commas)

probably not the most elegant solution, but you could loop over all unique `movieId`'s and extract the user-feedback:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

movies_df = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
tags_df = pd.read_csv("tags.csv")

movies_df["tag"] = np.tile("", len(movies_df))

for movieId in movies_df.movieId.unique():
    tag = tags_df[tags_df.movieId == movieId].tag.sum()
    movies_df[movies_df.movieId == movieId].tag = tag

print(movies_df.head())
```

not sure if the code actually works (as the data is only provided as images..)
hope this helps